# Iterate sequentially over two lists in R

Tags: r, function, loops, sequence

I have two df that look something like this

```
library(tidyverse)
iris <- iris%>% mutate_at((1:4),~.+2)
iris2 <- iris 
names(iris2)<-sub(".", "_", names(iris2), fixed = TRUE)
```

My aim is to reduce the values of the variables in `iris` that are above the maximum values of the corresponding variable in `iris2`, to match the maximum value in `iris2`.

I have written a function that does this.

```
max(iris$Sepal.Length) 
[1] 9.9
max(iris2$Sepal_Length)
[1] 7.9
# i want every value of iris that is >= to max value of iris2 to be equal to the max value of iris 2.

# my function:
fixmax<- function(data,data2,var1,var2) {
  data<- data %>% 
    mutate("{var1}" := ifelse(get(var1)>=max(data2[[var2]],na.rm = T),
                              max(data2[[var2]],na.rm = T),get(var1)))
  return(data)
}

# apply my function to a variable
tst_iris <- fixmax(iris,iris2,"Sepal.Length","Sepal_Length")
max(tst_iris$Sepal.Length)
7.9 # it works!
```

The challange I face is that I would like to iterate my function **sequentially** overtwo lists of variables- i.e. `Sepal.Length` with `Sepal_Length`, `Sepal.Width`with `Sepal_Width` etc.

Does anyone knows how I can do this?

I tried using `Map` but I am doing something wrong.

```
lst1 <- names(iris[,1:4])
lst2 <- names(iris2[,1:4])
final_iris<- Map(fixmax,iris, iris2,lst1,lst2)
```

My goal is to obtain a df (`final_iris`) where every variable has been adjusted using the criteria specified by `fixmax`.
I know I can do this by running my function on every variable like so.

```
final_iris <- iris
final_iris <- fixmax(final_iris,iris2,"Sepal.Length","Sepal_Length")
final_iris <- fixmax(final_iris,iris2,"Sepal.Width","Sepal_Width")
final_iris <- fixmax(final_iris,iris2,"Petal.Length","Petal_Length")
final_iris <- fixmax(final_iris,iris2,"Petal.Width","Petal_Width")
```

But in the real data, I have to run this operation tens of times and I would like to be able to loop my function sequentially.
Does anyone know how I loop my `fixmax` over `lst1` and `lst2` sequentially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your issue is related to the fact that dataframes are themselves lists. `Map()` expects the non-function arguments to be lists of the same length. Any arguments that are shorter than the longest list are "recycled" to match it's length.

Currently, you have:

```
final_iris<- Map(fixmax,iris, iris2,lst1,lst2)
```

This is actually equivalent to:

```
final_iris<- Map(fixmax,
                 list(iris$Sepal.Length,
                      iris$Sepal.Width,
                      iris$Petal.Length,
                      iris$Petal.Width,
                      iris$Species),
                 list(iris2$Sepal_Length,
                      iris2$Sepal_Width,
                      iris2$Petal_Length,
                      iris2$Petal_Width,
                      iris2$Species),
                 lst1,
                 lst2)
```

(To understand why, you must remember that dataframes like `iris` and `iris2` are, technically, under the hood, *lists of [atomic] vectors*.)

I suspect that you want `iris` and `iris2` to be supplied to each call to `fixmax()`. In order to have `Map()` recycle these two vectors, they need to be supplied as single-element lists. Like so:

```
final_iris<- Map(fixmax, list(iris), list(iris2),lst1,lst2)
```

To combine a list of dataframes into a single dataframe do

```
do.call(rbind, final_iris)
```

Comment: Thanks! the `final_iris<- Map(fixmax, list(iris), list(iris2),lst1,lst2)` appears to work. The only remaining challenge is that the outcome object is a list while I would like to have a data frame. basically, a single data frame with the variable modified. I tried to `unlist(final_iris)` but it does ot appear to work. do you know how I can do it?

Comment: I have updated the post to clarify the outcome I am looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than explicitly iterating over the different datasets and columns by name, you can take advantage of the vectorization built into `R`. If the dataframes have the same column/variable ordering a function mapped to both dataframes using `mapply` or `purrr::map2` will iterate column by column without the need to specify column names.

Given two input data frames (`df_small` and `df_big`) the steps are:

1. Calculate the max of each column in `df_small` to create `df_small_max`
2. Apply the `pmin` function to each column of `df_big` and each value of `df_small_max` using `mapply` (or `purr::map2_dfc` if you prefer `tidyverse` mapping)

```r
#set up fake data
df_small <- iris[,1:4]
df_big <- df_small + 2

# find max of each col in df_small
df_small_max <- sapply(df_small, max)

# replace values of df_big which are larger than df_small_max
df_big_fixed <- mapply(pmin, df_big, df_small_max)




# sanity check -- Note the change in Sepal.Width
df_small_max
#> Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#>          7.9          4.4          6.9          2.5
head(df_big, 3)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1          7.1         5.5          3.4         2.2
#> 2          6.9         5.0          3.4         2.2
#> 3          6.7         5.2          3.3         2.2
head(df_big_fixed, 3)
#>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> [1,]          7.1         4.4          3.4         2.2
#> [2,]          6.9         4.4          3.4         2.2
#> [3,]          6.7         4.4          3.3         2.2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is a mostly base way. I also renamed the variables because I had some trouble replicating since originally the approach would save over the `iris` object.

The approach is that instead of mutating a `data.frame` object, we instead only return the vector of the expected values from our modified function. Then, we re-assign those values back to our original `data.frame`.

```
fixmax2 = function(x, y) {
  max_y = max(y, na.rm = TRUE)
  ifelse(x >= max_y, max_y, y)
}
cols = which(sapply(df_plus, is.numeric))
df_plus[cols] = Map(fixmax2, df_plus[cols], df_iris[cols])
df_plus
```

Raw data:

```
library(dplyr)
df_plus = iris %>% mutate_at((1:4), ~. + 2) ## let's not save over iris
df_iris = iris
names(df_iris)<-sub(".", "_", names(df_iris), fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're expecting ?

```
my_a <- iris %>% mutate_at((1:4),~.+2)
iris2 <- iris
names(iris2)<-sub(".", "_", names(iris2), fixed = TRUE)

my_var <- which(my_a$Sepal.Length >= max(iris2$Sepal_Length) & my_a$Sepal.Width >= max(iris2$Sepal_Width))
if (length(my_var)) {
  my_a <- my_a[my_var,]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I would like to iterate a function over two lists sequentially, while your approach individuates the observations that meet certain criteria. A key limitation is that I would have to specify the criteria for every variable using your `my_var`approach. in the real dataset I have to iterate over hundred of variabels.

Comment: But this is giving the expected result based on your example ? So if you're having more criteria and/or dataframe can you give me more information maybe I just need to put my solution in a function and then iterate with a lapply for example.

Comment: no unfortunately the final object is not what  I wanted. I am looking for a way to iterate my function over two lists of variables producing a data frame with the modified variables as results. Your approach is not dealing with the iteration problem and deliver an object that individuates rows that I want to modify. It is a different outcome. But thank you very much for looking into this!

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify what the outcome should look like!

Answer (score 1):

Your function seems convoluted and hard to read at a first glance. We can tidy up the function to return max(x, max_val) for each value in a column with a quick function

```
#function to correct max  
adjust_max <- function(x, max_val) {  
  return(ifelse(x >= max_val, max_val, x))  
}
```

Finally, we want to apply this automatically and sequentially using the two dataframes. We will use a simple for loop. Code to set up the problem is attached.

```
#libraries
library(tidyverse)


#set up fake data
iris_big <- iris%>% mutate_at((1:4),~.+2)
iris_small <- iris 
names(iris_small)<- sub(".", "_", names(iris_small), fixed = TRUE)

#check which is the bigger one and the smaller
max(iris_big$Sepal.Length)  #bigger
max(iris_small$Sepal_Length)  #smaller


#function to correct max
adjust_max <- function(x, max_val) {
  return(ifelse(x >= max_val, max_val, x))
}


#apply it to get a final result
iris_final <- iris_big

# iterate over columns, assuming same positions
# you can edit the 1:ncol(iris_final) to only take the columns you want
for (i in 1:ncol(iris_final)) {
  #check numeric
  if (is.numeric(iris_final[,i])) {
    #applies the function - notice we call iris_final and iris_small
    iris_final[,i] <- sapply(iris_final[,i], 
                             adjust_max,
                             max_val = max(iris_small[,i]))
  }
}

#check answer is correct
apply(iris_final[,1:4], 2, max)
apply(iris_small[,1:4], 2, max)

tail(iris_final)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a `tidyverse` approach you can use `transmute` instead of `mutate`. `transmute` would return only one column in each iteration whereas `mutate` would return all the columns every time.

Apart from that to make it more `tidyverse` friendly I am using `.data` instead of `get`. Also using `pmin` instead of complicated `ifelse` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

fixmax<- function(data,data2,var1,var2) {
  data<- data %>%  transmute("{var1}" := pmin(.data[[var1]], max(data2[[var2]])))
  return(data)
}
```

To apply the function to each pair of columns you can use `map2_dfc` which will also combine the results in one dataframe.

```
lst1 <- names(iris[,1:4])
lst2 <- names(iris2[,1:4])
```

Compare the max values of two dataframes before applying the function.

```
map_dbl(iris[lst1], max)
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#         9.9          6.4          8.9          4.5 

map_dbl(iris2[lst2], max)

#Sepal_Length  Sepal_Width Petal_Length  Petal_Width 
#         7.9          4.4          6.9          2.5
```

Apply the function -

```
iris[lst1] <- map2_dfc(lst1, lst2, ~fixmax(iris, iris2, .x, .y))
```

Compare the max values of two dataframes after applying the function.

```
map_dbl(iris[lst1], max)

#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#         7.9          4.4          6.9          2.5 

map_dbl(iris2[lst2], max)
#Sepal_Length  Sepal_Width Petal_Length  Petal_Width 
#         7.9          4.4          6.9          2.5
```

Comment: Thanks did not know about transmutate. but it is super useful!!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using column indices; a complete (not including the data-frame construction) base R solution could look like:

```
# Resolve the indices of the numeric vectors in 
# iris: num_cols => integer vector
num_cols <- which(
  vapply(
      iris, 
      is.numeric, 
      logical(1)
    ),
  arr.ind = TRUE
)

# Map the pmin function over iris to select the
# minimum of the vector element in iris and the 
# maximum values of that vector in iris2: 
# iris => data.frame
iris[,num_cols] <- Map(function(i){
  pmin(
    iris[,i], 
    max(
      iris2[,i],
      na.rm = TRUE
      )
    )
  }, 
  num_cols
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a matrix of the max value repeated in each column and use `pmin` to take the minimum values between the max values in iris2 and the values in the other dataframe. I created a new fixmax function which only takes the two dataframes as arguments.

#### Preparing the data

```
library(tidyverse)

initial <- iris %>%  mutate_at(1:4, ~.+2)
iris2 <- iris 
names(iris2)<-sub(".", "_", names(iris2), fixed = TRUE)

print(max(initial$Sepal.Length))
# [1] 9.9
print(max(iris2$Sepal_Length))
# [1] 7.9
```

#### Creating the function

```
fixmax <- function(df, dfmax){
  
  colids <- which(unlist(lapply(dfmax, is.numeric)))
  dfmax <-  apply(dfmax[, colids], 2, max) %>% 
            matrix(nrow=nrow(dfmax), ncol=length(colids), byrow=TRUE) %>% 
            as.data.frame()
  
  df[, colids] <- pmin(df[,colids], dfmax)
  
  return(df)
}
```

#### Testing the function

```
newiris <- fixmax(initial, iris2)

print(max(newiris$Sepal.Length))
# [1] 7.9

assertthat::assert_that(!identical(newiris, iris2))
# [1] TRUE
assertthat::assert_that(all((initial == newiris) || (iris2 == newiris)))
# [1] TRUE
imax = apply(iris2[, 1:4], 2, max) %>% 
       matrix(nrow=nrow(iris2), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE) %>% 
       as.data.frame()
assertthat::assert_that(all(newiris[, 1:4] <= imax))
# [1] TRUE

print(head(newiris))
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          7.1         4.4          3.4         2.2  setosa
# 2          6.9         4.4          3.4         2.2  setosa
# 3          6.7         4.4          3.3         2.2  setosa
# 4          6.6         4.4          3.5         2.2  setosa
# 5          7.0         4.4          3.4         2.2  setosa
# 6          7.4         4.4          3.7         2.4  setosa
```